# Making an array within array of 3 table records using loop in Codeigniter

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

I am new in codeigniter framework. I making an array within array scenario for getting record of 3 tables.

I have categories then subcategories and then sub subcategories as you see it in the image

SmartPhones is category then Apple is subcategory and under subcategory is sub subcategory

[image]

**Controller file**

```
    public function index() {
    $all_devices = $this->devices_model->all_devices();
    $this->data['all_devices'] = array();
    if($all_devices)
    {
        foreach ($all_devices as $device) {
            $all_manufacturers = $this->manufacturers_model->all_manufacturers($device['id']);
            if(!empty($all_manufacturers))
            {
                $isProduct = false;
                foreach ($all_manufacturers as $key => $manufacture) {

                    $all_models = $this->models_model->all_models($manufacture['id']);

                    if($all_models)
                        {
                            $isProduct = true;
                        }
                    $all_manufacturers[$key]['model'] = $all_models;

                    if($isProduct)
                    {
                        $model_single["all_manufacturers"] = $all_manufacturers;
                        $this->data['all_devices'][] = $model_single;             
                    }  
                }
            }
        }
    }
    $this->load->view($this->theme.'products',$this->data);
}
```

**Models file**

```
public function all_devices()
{
     $result = $this->db->get("devices")->result_array();
     return $result;
}
public function all_manufacturers($device_id)
{
    $this->db->where("fk_device_id", $device_id);
    $result = $this->db->get("manufacture")->result_array();
    return $result;
}
public function all_models($id)
{
    $this->db->where("fk_manufactureid", $id);
    $result = $this->db->get("models")->result_array();
    return $result;
}
```

Issue is that I cannot make array in good way.